# Run time error of cin.get()

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
void cpp_string();
void cstyle_string();

int main()
{
  cpp_string();
  cstyle_string();

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void cpp_string()
{
  string fName, lName;
  char grade;
  int age;

  cout << "What is your first name?";
  getline(cin, fName);
  cout << "What is your last name?";
  getline(cin, lName);
  cout << "What letter grade do you deserve?";
  cin >> grade;
  cout << "What is your age?";
  cin >> age;

  cout << "Name: " << fName << ", " << lName << endl;
  cout << "Grade: " << grade << endl;
  cout << "Age: " << age << endl;

  return;
}

void cstyle_string()
{
  char fNm[20], lNm[20];
  char grade;
  int age;

  cout << "What is your first name?";
  cin.get(fNm, 20).get();
  cin.clear();
  cout << "What is your last name?";
  cin.get(lNm, 20).get();
  cout << "What letter grade do you deserve?";
  cin >> grade;
  cout << "What is your age?";
  cin >> age;

  cout << "Name: " << fNm << ", " << lNm << endl;
  cout << "Grade: " << grade << endl;
  cout << "Age: " << age << endl;

  return;
}
```

I'm getting output as

```
What is your first name?demiurge conon  
What is your last name?no  
What letter grade do you deserve?a  
What is your age?22  
Name: demiurge conon, no  
Grade: a  
Age: 22  
What is your first name?What is your last name?What letter grade do you deserve?What is your age?Name: ,  
Grade: ╠ 
Age: -858993460 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

but if I run `cstyle_string()` in different file then I'm not getting any errors code works perfectly.

I want to know why this is happening?

Comment: You are calling both `cpp_string()` and `cstyle_string()`. Call only one at a time. Because they consume the input.

Comment: They both run at different times....I mean first cpp_string() will run then after it returns, cstyle_string() will run. It worked well when i didn't use cin.get() in cpp_string(). Before this, i used cin>>fname for input and it worked well but it only takes a single word so i used get() to get a line of characters. Now code not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two question.

1. Redundant `\n`
2. the state of `cin`

The last `cin` in `cpp_string` is `cin >> age`.

It will leave a `\n` not extracted.

In first of `cstyle_string` is `cin.get(fNm, 20).get();`

> The delimiting character is not extracted from the input sequence if found, and remains there as the next character to be extracted from the stream

the `cin.get(FNm, 20)` will parse empty input before `\n`, and no characters are available in the stream in actually. In this case, the failbit flag will be set and next all `cin >>` operator will fail.

You can only call `cstyle_string` and press enter directly, the same thing will happen.

Comment: Thanks, new line has to be ignored. so used this line 

cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

before first cout in cstyle_string(), now it's working fine.